# How can I change the size of Array?(and how can I throw the trash values of Array?)

Tags: arrays, c, string

Hi I wrote a program below. It's a program, that saves the letters backwards in an Array, when the user gives a string.

```
int main(){

    char string[100];
    char gnirts[100];

    int i, j;

    printf("String : ");
    scanf("%s", string);

    int size = sizeof(string)/sizeof(char);

    for(i=size-1, j=0; 0<=i ; i--, j++){
        gnirts[j] = string[i]; 
    }

    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        if(gnirts[i])
            printf("%c", gnirts[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I gave the program
`String : asdf`
and received
`�i���i���i�fdsa`

At the beginning I set the size of `string` as 100. And then with the line `int size = sizeof(string)/sizeof(char);` I set Array `string` with the size, that depends on what the User gives. But it's not working. I got a trash values before the meaningful values.

How can I delete the trash values and set a new size of the Array `string` and get the right result?

Thank you.

Comment: Use `strlen()` to get the length of the input, not `sizeof`

Comment: `size` will always be `100`, since it's based on the array's declared size, not the input length.

Comment: Don't forget to add a trailing null to `gnirts`

Comment: To add on to what the others have said already, all strings in C end with 0 ('\0') so you could loop through until you find the 0 at the end. Also when copying the array you should place said 0 at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof(string)` gives you the size of the entire array in bytes, not the number of characters in the string.

To get the length of the string, you want `strlen`:

```
int size = strlen(string);
```

Comment: Thank u! It works!

Comment: @salami2 Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.